# WAS8.5.5.12 and JAVA8 and JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere

Getting below exception while deploying the application using WAS8.5.5.12 and Java 8.
please help me to resolve this

Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...
                                 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: wsjar:file:/C:/xxxxxxxx/appxx/appxx-lib/lib/jsf-impl-2.0.6-FCS.jar!/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl': java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:293)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.setResourceHandler(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:767)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:314)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:216)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:338)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5396)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:268)
    ... 33 more

[14/11/17 18:40:36:413 EST] 00000051 config        E   Critical error during deployment: 
                                 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5396)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899)
    at

[14/11/17 18:40:36:461 EST] 00000051 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_7404068f_17.11.14_18.40.36.4132426497673250153005.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated 1341
[14/11/17 18:40:36:461 EST] 00000051 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5396)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899)

[14/11/17 18:40:36:461 EST] 00000051 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_7404068f_17.11.14_18.40.36.4619182433776222551682.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup 131
[14/11/17 18:40:36:462 EST] 00000051 config        E   Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;

  org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener

```
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:196)
at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:108)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:326)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextDestroyed(WebApp.java:1799)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.destroy(WebApp.java:3165)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.destroy(WebAppImpl.java:1566)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:97)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5396)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

[14/11/17 18:40:36:462 EST] 00000051 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [appxxEAR8#appxx.war]:.Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[14/11/17 18:40:36:514 EST] 00000051 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_7404068f_17.11.14_18.40.36.4956213751987669642611.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextDestroyed 1405
[14/11/17 18:40:36:514 EST] 00000051 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextDestroyed SRVE0285E: Exception caught while destroying context: {0}
                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;

  org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener

```
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:196)
at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getApplication(FacesContextImplBase.java:131)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._dispatchApplicationEvent(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:272)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.destroyFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:305)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(StartupServletContextListener.java:153)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextDestroyed(WebApp.java:1799)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.destroy(WebApp.java:3165)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.destroy(WebAppImpl.java:1566)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:97)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5396)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

[14/11/17 18:40:36:683 EST] 00000051 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application appxx
[14/11/17 18:40:36:698 EST] 00000051 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_7404068f_17.11.14_18.40.36.683260421270110660920.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer 736
[14/11/17 18:40:36:714 EST] 00000051 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_7404068f_17.11.14_18.40.36.6981786598416651387312.txt com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WebContainerImpl.install 124
[14/11/17 18:40:36:729 EST] 00000051 DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, appxx.war, of application, appxxEAR8.ear/deployments/appxxEAR8, failed to start
[14/11/17 18:40:36:729 EST] 00000051 ApplicationMg W   WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, appxxEAR8
[14/11/17 18:40:36:729 EST] 00000051 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: appxxEAR8
[14/11/17 18:40:36:761 EST] 00000051 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: appxxuiEAR8
[14/11/17 18:40:36:761 EST] 00000051 SystemOut     O WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
[14/11/17 18:40:36:761 EST] 00000051 SystemOut     O WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
[14/11/17 18:40:36:792 EST] 00000051 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_7404068f_17.11.14_18.40.36.7611284141919601609807.txt com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl 2065
[14/11/17 18:40:36:792 EST] 00000051 CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=appxxEAR8 in BLA WebSphere:blaname=appxxEAR8 failed to start.
[14/11/17 18:40:36:792 EST] 00000051 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_7404068f_17.11.14_18.40.36.7921253433477090411667.txt com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl 297
[14/11/17 18:40:36:792 EST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Error creating component com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@2d937a39
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl.join(WsComponentImpl.java:432)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1295)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.start(ApplicationServerImpl.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:702)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:406)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:169)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:433)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5396)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899)
    at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved Myself By adding Parent_last in EAR.

Thank You.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more information about this. Is this something class loader configuration?